# Can't build Angular 5 with AOT systemjs

Tags: angular

I've been looking for a solution for my problem with no luck. So maybe someone can help me with it.

I'm upgrading from ng 4.4.4 to 5.0.1 everything seems to work properly in JIT mode but when I try to compile to AOT mode it doesn't work.

The error says that module app.module.ngfactory can not be found and it seems to make sense since it is not being generated for some reason.

These are my files:

main-aot.ts

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from '../Scripts/dist/aot/tsScripts/app.module.ngfactory';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

tsconfig-aot.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "Scripts/dist/aot",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types/"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "tsScripts/app.module.ts",
    "tsScripts/main-aot.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "Scripts/dist/aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true,
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

And the command I'm using to compile is:

```
ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json && rollup -c rollup-config.js
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I moved my project structure to use angular-cli and everything worked again.